Can someone identify this electrical connector?
Can someone identify this electrical connector?
It's a 2 pin DC connector.
It's also "keyed" with a small bump on the flat spot.
It's part of a battery charing port of my son "Backfire" G2 electric Skateboard.
It's next to impossible to find online without an associated name.


Have seen this or something very similar on sealed equipment, I believe the plug is ridged and/or an o-ring involved as well?

Closest I can find: https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?N=&n=led_lighting_circ_conn&c=LED%20M_P_1 no PN or source or anything though.

Thanks, I went down that road too, but the connector seems to be a little different and not something thats searchable, but appreciate the help.

It's always a good idea when identifying something, to post pictures of the relevant details of the thing. For a connector, the connecting elements are relevant. Also dimensions makes it easier

It's probably a Chinese waterproof connector.  A common type for ebikes is 'Julet' but it's not that - many of them are custom overmoulds.  Best I can find with a quick Aliexpress search ('connector 2 pin waterproof') is the '08A' from an Aliexpress listing 08A Super Mini Quick Connector 2Pin 0.3/0.5 Square 1M 3M Aviation Plug Male-female Butt Waterproof Industrial Power Outdoor LED and a brief Alibaba search suggests the manufacturer of that may be Kunshan Rcd Electronics Co., Ltd, but we don't really have enough details to confirm.


Outstanding and thank you! The measurements seem to be an exact match my connector dimensions. I've searched aliexpress endlessly and cold never even come close to a match. Very much appreciate the help!
